# Redirect url but not entire directory

Tags: regex, .htaccess, redirect

I researched this for a long time but could not find a working solution. We have pretty urls which look like directories "Magento": `https://www.demosite.com/mattress/firm-mattresses`. I want to redirect that url to another page. For demo purposes lets say that we redirect it to `https://www.demosite.com/mattress`.

However, I don't want anything after that to be redirected. Eg. `https://www.demosite.com/mattress/firm-mattresses/plush-mattress` should still go to that url and not get redirected.

What I have used it this:

```
Redirect 301 /mattress/firm-mattresses https://www.demosite.com/mattress
```

However, anything coming after firm-mattresses gets redirected also. Any guidance in this area would be appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should use `RedrectMatch` with regex support to match only intended part:

```
RedirectMatch 301 ^/mattress/firm-mattresses/?$ https://www.demosite.com/mattress
```